# How to add a dynamic column in the middle in react?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

We're using ag-grid and a column has to be added dynamically in the third index. I'm able to add a column dynamically in the end in react using the following code:

```
let headers = $this.state.empHeaders;
      empList.org.forEach(item => {
        if(item.check === 'xyz'){
          headers.push({ field:'name', headerName:'NAME',cellRenderer:'empName'});
        }
      })
```

How to specify on where to add the dynamic column? For ex: How to add new column in the third position?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are in the right spot. Just you are pushing at the end. So change the code to insert the item on the third position or your specific position.

```js
let headers = $this.state.empHeaders;

empList.org.forEach(item => {
  if (item.check === 'xyz') {
    // Specify the index where you want to add the new column (e.g., 2 for the third position)
    const insertionIndex = 2;

    // Check if the index is within the valid range
    if (insertionIndex >= 0 && insertionIndex <= headers.length) {
      // Use splice to insert the new column at the specified index
      headers.splice(insertionIndex, 0, { field: 'name', headerName: 'NAME', cellRenderer: 'empName' });
    } else {
      console.error(`Invalid insertion index: ${insertionIndex}`);
    }
  }
});

// Update the state with the modified headers
$this.setState({ empHeaders: headers });
```